# Material button in java?

Tags: java, swing, material-ui, awt

Can we use material UI in java?
Basically, I am making a calculator in eclipse using swing and awt and I want to try materialUI, so I want to use the material button in it.
Is it possible?

Comment: What's stopping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You could use Material UI with Java.  Implement your calculator as a webapp and use Material UI components to implement the calculator (web) UI to run in the user's web browser.

But it doesn't make sense to use Material UI with Swing / AWT.

- Material UI is a Javascript component library that runs *in the user's web browser*.
- Swing / AWT are for implementing user interfaces *on the user's desktop*.

(Trying to use Material UI with Swing / AWT would be like trying to put wheels on a fish.)

---

There is nothing preventing you from designing and implementing cool buttons (e.g. buttons that look like Material buttons) in Java using Swing / AWT as the foundation.  It would "just" be a Java coding exercise; see Andrew Thompson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68650910/139985) for some a starting point.

But my advice: don't bother.  It would be a waste of effort ... IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> .. looks cool ..

If it is purely about the look of Swing GUI controls, that could be implemented using a custom [look-and-feel](/questions/tagged/look-and-feel). See the [Modifying the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) lesson in the tutorial for details. Note there are also many 3rd party look and feel implementations that might come close to what you think is 'cool'.